# Why I can't delete a folder in "program files"?

Tags: vbscript, access-denied, filesystemobject

I run the follow script with admin rights:

```
Dim FSO
Set FSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim tempName, fullTempName, tempFolder
tempName = FSO.GetTempName
fullTempName = "c:\program files\" + tempName
Set tempFolder = fso.CreateFolder( fullTempName )
tempFolder.Attributes = 0
tempFolder.Delete( True )
```

I can create the folder but I can't delete it. I receive the error message:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Permission denied.
```

translated from German:

```
Laufzeitfehler in Microsoft VBScript: Erlaubnis verweigert.
```

The reseting of the attributes has no effect. It is continue 16 (read-only). Why this error occur and how can I resolve it?

Comment: *"Permission denied"* - seems fairly self explanatory.

Comment: @Lankymart No, this not self explanatory because I have create the file a line before. If I have no permissions then the createFolder should also failed.

Comment: Didn't say you have no permissions, just because you can create doesn't automatically mean you can also delete. The script says it's a permission issue so the likely hood is it's a permission issue. Check through the NTFS permissions for that folder.

Comment: @Lankymart And why the shell call from the same process can delete the folder?

Comment: If I was to guess, uses a different or elevated context. I know this isn't IIS but found this interesting... [INFO: The Run Method of the Wscript.shell Object Executes Commands in System Context in IIS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/278319)

Comment: Did you try to use the German name `fullTempName = "c:\Programme\" + tempName` as shown in Explorer?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the follow workaround. I replace the line of "tempFolder.Delete" with:

```
Dim wshShell
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wshShell.Run wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe /c rd """ & fullTempName & """" ), 0
```